# Rails view/controller has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this relations:

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :community_people
  has_many :people, :through => :community_people
end

class CommunityPerson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :community
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :community_persons
  has_many :communities, :through => :community_persons
end
```

I can CRUD communities, but i've been searching how to in the controller/view add many people to that community, then show them but i can't find and answer.

I'll really appreciate your help!

Comment: [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) makes it easier to handle nested forms. Nested forms are forms that handle nested models and attributes in one form; e.g. a project with its tasks or an invoice with its line items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is by using the [Rails form options helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html):

```
<%= form_for(@community) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :person_ids %>
    <%= f.collection_select :person_ids, multiple: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class CommunityControllers
  ...

  def community_attributes
    params.permit(:foo, :bar, person_ids: [])
  end
end
```

But I would try to go with a less awkward and more descriptive naming scheme like:

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :citizenships
  has_many :citizens, through: :citizenships                      
end

class Citizenship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :community
  belongs_to :citizen, class_name: "Person"
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :citizenships, foreign_key: 'citizen_id'
  has_many :communities, through: :citizenships
end
```